# How to reate custom passport strategy in nestJS? Circular structure error

Tags: node.js, authentication, nestjs, passport.js, passport-local

I'm new working with nestjs. I've implemented Local and JWT strategies which already work well and now I need one more strategy that authenticates the user by a string which I call tokenRegister.

I don't get what is wrong. The error is

```
[Nest] 25976  - 16/03/2023 23:11:17   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Socket'
    |     property 'parser' -> object with constructor 'HTTPParser'
    --- property 'socket' closes the circle

TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Socket'
    |     property 'parser' -> object with constructor 'HTTPParser'
    --- property 'socket' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at SelectQueryBuilder.<anonymous> (src\query-builder\SelectQueryBuilder.ts:2121:57)
    at step (\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:144:27)
    at Object.next (\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:125:57)
    at \tslib\tslib.js:118:75
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:114:16)
    at SelectQueryBuilder.loadRawResults (\node_modules\typeorm\query-builder\SelectQueryBuilder.js:1639:38)
    at SelectQueryBuilder.<anonymous> (\src\query-builder\SelectQueryBuilder.ts:2050:37)
    at step (\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:144:27)
```

The first thing I did was to install passport custom

```
npm install passport-custom
```

Then I created a class

```
nest g cl modules/auth/strategies/custom.strategy --flat --no-spec
```

### Custom strategy class implementation

```
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Strategy } from 'passport-custom';

import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class CustomStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'custom') {

    constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
        super();
    }
    
    async validate(tokenRegister: string) {
        const user = await this.authService.validateUserByToken(tokenRegister);
        if (!user) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException('No permitido');
        }

        return user;
    }
}
```

### Auth controller:

```
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('custom'))
@Post('loginByToken')
loginByToken(@Req() req: Request) {
    const user = req.user as User;
    if (user.image)
        user.image = bufferToString(user.image);

    return this.authService.generateJWTByToken(user);
}
```

### Auth module:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    UsersModule,
    PassportModule,
    JwtModule.registerAsync({
      inject: [config.KEY],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigType<typeof config>) => {
        return {
          secret: configService.jwtSecret,
          signOptions: {
            expiresIn: '365d', //12h
          },
        };
      },
    }),
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, LocalStrategy, JwtStrategy, CustomStrategy],
  controllers: [AuthController],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

### Auth service:

```
    async validateUserByToken(tokenRegister: string) {
        const user = await this.userService.findOneByToken(tokenRegister);

        if (user) {
            if (!user.isAllowed)
                throw new ConflictException('Usuario restringido.');

            return user;
        }

        return null;
    }

  async generateJWTByToken(user: User) {
        const payload: PayloadToken = { role: user.role, sub: user.id };
        const userFind = await this.userService.findOneByToken(user.tokenRegister);
    
        return {
              access_token: this.jwtService.sign(payload),
              userFind,
        };
  }
```

### User service

```
  async findOneByToken(token: string) {
        const user = await this.userRepo.findOne({
            where: {
                tokenRegister: token
            }
        });
    
        if (!user)
            throw new NotFoundException(`Usuario no encontrado.`);
        
        if (!user.isAllowed)
            throw new NotFoundException(`Usuario #${user.id} no permitido.`);
            
        return this.userData(user);
  }
```

Please help me.

I researched on the internet but there is no much documentation about custom strategy. And my implementation looks similar to these: [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65782535/nestjs-custom-passportstrategy-not-registered-when-shared-through-library)

Please help me find my mistake

Comment: I found out validate returns a promise and I need to obtain the tokenRegister from the req.body